# Controlling the order of execution of multiple threads in sequential order

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to test a multithread scenario,

I am having multiple (3) thread groups in a test plan and I need to control the execution order of thread group.

And I need to implement the following scenario.
Thread group 1 - Request creation 
Thread group 2 - Approval level one 
Thread group 3 - Approval level Two

If a request has been created successfully for a user then only thread group 2 should be executed if approval 1  has been accepted then thread group 3 should be executed.

Request creation failed then thread group 2 and thread group 3 should not be executed.

Request creation successful thread 2 failed(request rejected) then thread group 3 should not be executed.

I am expecting if any of the thread group is failed (rejected) then it should not continue the flow of execution it should stop the flow.

Comment: Why are you keeping each request under different thread groups? you could have different HTTP Request under one thread group and use an if controller.

Comment: Approval 1 and 2 are different users and flow for those are approval users are completely different from each other that makes me to login in every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop it in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) setting,

on `Action to be taken after a Sampler Error` choose  `Stop Test/Stop Test Now/Stop Thread`

> Stop Thread - current thread exits
>
> Stop Test - the entire test is stopped at the end of any current samples.
>
> Stop Test Now - the entire test is stopped abruptly. Any current samplers are interrupted if possible.

Comment: failed in my case rejected. Approver level user can either approve or reject the request created. If the request is rejected I don't want to run thread group 3 in my test plan.

Comment: @KarthikeyanU but if you set Thread Group 2and 1 with Stop Test Now it won't continue. Also make sure in test plan `Run Test Group consecutively` is checked